# Custom Page Size in Wicked_PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

Wicked_pdf docs show that I can use the following to change the page size:

```
render :pdf => 'file_name', :page_size => "b10"
```

However, this is limited to "named" page sizes such as "A4" or "Letter".  I would like to use wkhtmltopdf's `page_height` and `page_width` properties, but the following appears to have no effect in wicked_pdf:

```
render :pdf => 'file_name', :page_height => 1, :page_width => 1
```

Is there a way to declare custom PDF page size in wicked_pdf?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looking at the wkhtmltopdf documentation it looks like you'll need to specify a unit of measurement for custom page sizes, eg:

```
render :pdf => 'file_name', :page_height => '5in', :page_width => '7in'
```

This was merged into the trunk of wkhtmltopdf in Dec 2009, so you'll want to make sure you have a fairly new version of the binary (0.9.9 or higher should be fine) if it still doesn't work.

Comment: I've got `wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.9.9.3)` and `wicked_pdf (0.11.0)` and `:page_height` and `:page_width` does not work :(

Comment: I had to specify `:page_size => nil` and then it works